# How to properly convert string to url? c#

Tags: c#

I need to convert the a link from the database to url. For far I am not able to convert it properly because there is some characters like \ appearing the link that I am retrieving from database. How can I properly convert it?

This how my link looks when getting from code.

```
"\"/Reading/04082017042819PM.jpg\""
```

This how the entire url looks like.

```
"http://mypc.rocketserver.com/\"/Reading/04082017042819PM.jpg\"
```

This how I'm converting it.

```
 string imagelink = mmr.Imagelink;

 string link = String.Format("<a href=\"http://mypc.rocketserver.com/"+imagelink+"\" >View Image</a>");
```

This how the link string looks like.

```
"<a href=\"http://mypc.rockertserver.com/\"/Reading/04082017042819PM.jpg\"\" >View Image</a>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get the image link from the dB remove the escaped double quotes:

```
string imagelink = imagelink.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```